# Excel formatting for making values equal

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working in Excel and I am wanting to find out if there are matches in one sheet based on a list in the other sheet.

I have pasted the values in a list and want to return their corresponding value from another sheet. The cells that contain letters and numbers work correctly (example: `D5765000`), but for some reason if the cell has only numbers, Excel is not able to find it in the other sheet, even though it exists.

I pasted a value  `745‐3000`  in the list and I am looking for this corresponding value in another sheet. It shows as `#N/A` on the lookup indicating it doesn't exist in the other sheet. However, if I delete the `745‐3000` and manually type `745-3000`, then Excel somehow does recognize the value and find it in the other sheet.

The formatting is exactly the same in both and there are no spaces in either list. I cannot understand why Excel won't recognize the pasted value of `745-3000`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel is reading the "-" with a different code than it is with a manually typed "-"

Isolate the "-" and use to find and replace. Does some data contain multiple offending "-"'s?

```
=REPLACE(H4,FIND(G4,H4),1,"-")
```

[image]

EDIT: Switched from code to Unicode
TY @ron

We find the offending char using the set up pictured below:

[image]

Some of the formulas used:

Yellow Cells:

```
=UNICODE(MID($A$3,C4,1))
```

Light Blue Cells:

```
=UNICODE(MID($E$3,C4,1))
```

At the bottom we check to see what code we get from the value. I get a VALUE mark with from the unicode value of "-"

Comment: Good approach.  Suggest that instead of using the `CODE` function, use the `UNICODE` function and you will see that the value is `8208` which is a Unicode hyphen.  `63` is what gets returned when values are out of the range for the `CODE` function.